# How to split some parts of a line?

Tags: python, loops, split

So I have a bunch of lines (productions) like either of the following:

```
VBD -> 'RATTLED'
PP -> CC PP|<PP-LOC-CC-PP>
```

There is always one part on the LHS and then an arrow then either one or two parts on the RHS. How can I store them or call them? (For example iterating through all the lines (productions) and check if the LHS is VBD or the RHS is RATTLED (for the first pattern) or the RHS0 is CC and the RHS1 is PP-PP| 
(for the second pattern) )?

Again, the pattern in the productions always follows one of the following:

```
A -> 'B'
```

or

```
C -> D E
```

A, B, C, D and E can be anything (Numbers, letters, signs etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to split each line into a head (e.g. `VBD`) and a tail (e.g. `'RATTLED'`), one easy way to do this would be to use the `split` operator like so:

```
for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split(" -> ")
    head = split_line[0]
    tail = split_line[1]
```

This assumes that every single line has only one incidence of " -> ", and that each line has a space on each side of the "->" separator.

I'm not sure I understand the specifics of your implementation, but if you wanted to check whether any given tail was like `'RATTLED'` or like `CC PP|<PP-LOC-CC-PP>`, you could iterate through the tail like so:

```
for token in tail:
    if token[0] == "'":
        # this is a string, like 'B'
    else:
        # this is like D E etc.
        two_part_style_split = token.split(' ')
```

`two_part_style_split` will look something like so:

```
['CC', 'PP<PP-LOC-CC-PP>']
```

Comment: It doesn't catch the two parts of the RHS in the second pattern!

Comment: @sabzdarsabz Okay, I think maybe by LHS and RHS you mean "left hand side" and "right hand side"? That's a little confusing to me and I'm not sure people are going to get that immediately, particularly given how the text you're parsing is pretty dense and confusing.

Comment: @sabzdarsabz I'm assuming what you mean by "two parts" means the two parts separated by the pipe? If so, I've updated this so that it works.

Comment: Yes Right Hand Side and Left Hand Side. In the first pattern I care about LHS and the string that is inside ' ' and for the second pattern I care about the LHS and the RHS0 and RHS1

Comment: @sabzdarsabz That's working now - I wasn't entirely sure how you defined the first and second half of the tail.

Comment: In the second pattern, the split factor should be space since RHS0 is CC and RHS1 is PP|<PP-LOC-CC-PP>

Comment: @sabzdarsabz That's the kind of thing you should've put in your question - it'll help prevent a lot of these confusions. I've edited the code.

Comment: I appreciate it. One more thing: I care about B, not 'B'. How can I extract B, knowing that the length of B is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to break out the parts. I stripped whitespace in a second step to keep the regex from looking too bad.

```
import re

tests = ["VBD -> 'RATTLED'", "PP -> CC PP|<PP-LOC-CC-PP>"]

# use positive lookahead to find everything before ->,
# then everything between -> and (optional) |
# and everything after |
split_re = re.compile(r"(.*(?=->))->([^|]+)\|?(.*)?")

def parse(txt):
    # pull out the values then strip any surrounding whitespace
    return (t.strip() for t in split_re.match(txt).groups())

for test in tests:
    a, b, c = parse(test)
    print a,b,c
```

A more complicated regex lets you skip stripping the values in a separate step, at the loss of readability:

```
split_re = re.compile(r"\s*(.*(?=\s*->))\s*->\s*(.*(?=\s*(?:\|)?)+)\s*\|?\s*(.*)?")
for test in tests:
    a, b, c = split_re.match(test).group()
    print a,b,c
```